# Interpolate Latitude and Longitude for a 2D image

Tags: geometry, geolocation, gis, interpolation, latitude-longitude

I have a 2D image.
There are 4 fixed points (xy coordinates) in the image where I have corresponding Latitude and Longitude coordinates.

How can I calculate the latitude and longitude for any of the points in that Image?

> eg:
>
> - X: 45,  Y: 27  --> Lat: 8.559631° Lon: 76.877531°
> - X: 535, Y: 78  --> Lat: 8.555131° Lon: 76.877706°
> - X: 630, Y: 980 --> Lat: 8.555386° Lon: 76.886261°
> - X: 50, Y: 890  --> Lat: 8.559433° Lon: 76.886553°

I am trying to write a function that returns Lat and Long for a given XY coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know anything more about the [map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections)? If you do, then you might be able to fit the parameters of that map projection to your four points.

Without knowledge of the projection, I'd probably go with [fitting a projective transformation to your four points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416). But that's mainly because it's a tool I'm very familiar with.

For small areas of the earth, the differences between the different map projections are small, too. For any common projection the map from spherical coordinates to map coordinates can be approximated using an affine map at small scale. And an affine map is defined by three points and their images.

So from that perspective, three points would be enough to get a rough answer to your question, and without knowing the map projection it's not clear how a fourth point can add value. Using the projective map is not terribly well motivated from a geometric perspective, but at the same time it doesn't hurt either. If your projection is well described by the affine map, the fourth point won't significantly change that map. On the other hand if the affine map is not a good approximation, using the fourth point for a projective interpolation will at least map all four reference points exactly. Whether that will do any good for other points is best tried in an experiment.